# Can I have a sequence of events kick in on javascript .click function?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Good day!

I have sequence of events I would like to happen in order within an onclick function of JavaScript. However, when I add a couple of .post functions that updates a db, it does not work. Is it not possible to have more than 1 .post functions within an onclick function?  Here's my code, adding some more text here as the site won't let me post saying I need to add more details because I have posted mostly code. Please help, looking forward to your assistance

```
$('#vesmos').click(function(){
    var dt = new Date();
    var dformat = dt.getFullYear() + "/"
                + (dt.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + dt.getDate()  + " "  
                + dt.getHours() + ":"  
                + dt.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + dt.getSeconds();
    //set start and end date on form fields
    if($.trim($('#stdt').val()) == ''){
        $('#stdt').val(dformat);
     }

    $('#enddt').val(dformat);

    //update rt table close rt log (code does not when I add this function)
    $.post("closert-docadminus.php",
    {
        empname: $("#empname").val(),

    });

    //calculate start and end date
    var strt = $('#stdt').val();
    var end = $('#enddt').val();

    var d2 = new Date(strt);
    var d1 = new Date(end);
    $('#insec').val(parseFloat(((d1-d2)/1000).toFixed(2)));
    $('#inmin').val(parseFloat(((d1-d2)/60000).toFixed(2)));
    $('#inhrs').val(parseFloat(((d1-d2)/3600000).toFixed(2)));

    //save to ams table logs
    $.post("savesettings.php",
    {
        empname: $("#empname").val(),
        task: $("#task").val(),
        dttoday: $("#dttoday").val(),
        stdt: $("#stdt").val(),
        enddt: $("#enddt").val(),
        insec: $("#insec").val(),
        inmin: $("#inmin").val(),
        inhrs: $("#inhrs").val(),
        pltform: $("#pltform").val(),

    });

    //clear textboxes
    $('#stdt').val("");
    $('#enddt').val("");
    $('#task').val("");
    $('#pltform').val("");


    //fill textboxes
    $('#task').val("Mail Open/Sort");
    $('#pltform').val("VES");
    $('#stdt').val(dformat);
    $('#statype').val("Occupancy");
    $('#statprio').val("Primary");

    // save log to rt table (code does not when I add this function)
    save to realtime
    $.post("savert-docadminus.php",
    {
        empname: $("#empname").val(),
        task: $("#task").val(),
        stdt: $("#stdt").val(),

    });
});
```

Comment: You can have multiple post events. My guess is you are expecting something to act synchronously when it is asynchronous.

Comment: You don't need to clear a textbox before you fill it in with a new value, but that shouldn't cause a problem. You also don't need to put the values into the textboxes just to send them with `$.post()`.

Comment: `$.post()` (and ajax in general) is asynchronous; your code does not wait for each request to complete before continuing.

Comment: @ChrisG But he doesn't use the results, so it's not clear that it matters.

Comment: Does each script require that the previous script have completed, or are they independent?

Comment: True, there is a syntax error in there though which would explain why the final request doesn't run at all: `save to realtime`

Comment: @ChrisG The comment saying "code does not when I add this function" seems to be for the question, it probably caused wrapping that's not in the real code.

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks for your responses, what I was trying to do is for each of the actions to happen in order, the first action to happen first before the next one... @Barmar correct, I need to have the actions completed in order... is this possible?

Comment: `$.post()` has an optional callback function argument. Kick off the next action in the callback function of the previous one.

Comment: If I can just have the basic syntax of how this is done please?

Answer (score 1):

You can have enormous events. This is not working because of asynchronous nature of Javascript.
All the I/O calls are asynchronous, so third call can finish first but second call can finish last.
You should learn more about Javascript Event loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to make is a set of concurrent [XMLHTTPRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Depending on the browser, you're going to have a set of maximum concurrent XHRs, there's a list [here](https://docs.pushtechnology.com/cloud/latest/manual/html/designguide/solution/support/connection_limitations.html). But even if they are too many, they will get queued and so the browser sends them in the future.

You are trying to make 3 concurrent XHRs in a click event handler, I don't see how that is a problem. Just saying 'it does not work' is not enough information on the problem, you need to dig and debug.

Here's what I recommend you to do:

1, Open the "Console" tab in the developer tools and check that you don't have any JavaScript errors in the console that prevent the XHRs from being dispatched.

2, Open the "Network" tab in the developer tools and check that the XHRs are effectively being dispatched; if they are, check what's the server response.

3, In your .post calls append .done and .fail callbacks in order to confirm what is the server responding, for example:

```
$.post("some.php", data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" })
  .done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
  })
  .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
  });
```

That should lead you to the root cause(s) of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Given that the OP clarified in the comments section that 'the problem' is: Dispatching the XHRs sequentially one after another, I'm adding a second answer on how to achieve it, but first, I'm going to try to explain in brief why adding a $.post call after another doesn't work.

XMLHTTPRequests are asynchronous by default. This forces you to think in an asynchronous domain and assume that calling:

```
asyncFunction1() ($.post)
asyncFunction2() ($.post)
```

doesn't mean that asyncFunction2 will be executed when asyncFunction1 ends its execution

1. This doesn't mean that JavaScript is parallel - multi-threaded. JavaScript is single-threaded and asynchronous, it uses an event loop for resolving code execution. Learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).
2. Ajax (XMLHTTPRequests - $.post) is a feature that is browser specific... The browser might open a separate thread in order to send the request but it doesn't really matter because remember, at the programming language level (JavaScript) we don't have threads.

Weird right, so back to the issue, What if we want to execute code right after an asynchronous function ends?

There are multiple patterns for achieving this:

1. [Callbacks](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced?gi=12c61a34f418)
2. [Promises](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-promises/)
3. [Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

And typically, an asynchronous function should provide you with an API for doing this, at least a good old callback.

According to the jQuery.post ($.post) [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), you can add a callback like this:

```
$.post('url', data).done(function (response1) {
    // Next code here
})
```

Which will lead you to:

```
$.post('url1', data1).done(function (response1) {
    // The first XHR finished successfully, we send the second
    $.post('url2', data2).done(function (response2) {
        $.post('url2', data2).done(function (response2) {
            // The second XHR finished successfully, we send the third and so on
            $.post('url3', data3).done(function (response3) {...})
        })
    })
})
```

Which will eventually lead you to say

"That code nesting doesn't look good and easy to maintain, how can I make it cleaner?"

Congratulations, you've entered the domain of [**Callback Hells**](http://callbackhell.com/)